# phantomjs in Java blocked in process.waitFor()

Tags: java, phantomjs

A simple example of using phantomJs in Java will block undefinitely:

```
public void runPhantomJs(String path, String command) {
    Process process;
    String outFile = "a11.txt";
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path+ " " + command + " > " +outFile);

        int exitStatus = process.waitFor();

        //String status = (exitStatus == 0 ? "SUCCESS:" : "ERROR:");
        File f = new File(outFile);
        if (f.exists()) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f),"UTF-8"));

            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }

            in.close();
            System.out.println(str);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The script execute is very simple, but it returns a whole page on the console:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.open('http://www.google.com/', function(status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('1');
    phantom.exit();
} else {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
}
});
```

Note that on the pasted code I've added a  "> a11.txt" to see if it worked better to read a file instead of reading the output directly. It should be faster, but for some reason it doesn't work. I suppose the redirection > doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it's waiting for you to consume the input/outputstream.. even if  there are none?

Comment: A breakpoint after the waitFor() is not reached. waitFor wait until the process is ended, so it should work. If I use a simpler script ( console.log('success!'); it works.

Comment: Try consuming the streams anyway in a separate thread while your main thread blocks

Comment: Then how do I stop both threads?

Answer (score 0):

So I got my code to work. Apparently the output of phantomjs has to be read or the buffer will fill up completely, blocking further execution.

So I think your code will work if you modify it like so:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path+ " " + command + " > " +outFile);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
bis.close();
process.waitFor();
...
```

If it doesn't work, try using ProcessBuilder. This is my working code:
    try {
        String phantomJsExe = configuration.getPhantomJsExe().toString();
        String phantomJsScript = configuration.getPhantomJsScript().toString();
        String urlsTextFile = configuration.getPhantomJsUrlsTextFile().toString();

```
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(phantomJsExe, phantomJsScript, urlsTextFile).start();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
    bis.close();
    process.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```